# How to create CVPixelBuffer from pixel data with YUVFormat

Tags: ios, swift

I'm **focus** to create CVPixelBuffer with bytes data **(YUV422)**, this format is my goal but it doesn't work

```swift
var yuv422Array = [UInt16](repeating: 0x0000, count: rows*cols)
yuv422Array[0] = 0x0000
let bytesPerRow = cols * 2
CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, cols, rows, 
                             kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr16, &baseAddr, bytesPerRow, 
                             nil, nil, nil, &pixelBuffer)

//...

print(pixelBuffer == nil) // false
print(CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer) == nil) // true ❌ (CIImage is nil)
```

I'm also trying to create with BGRA data, it doesn't work too.

```swift
var rgbArray = [UInt32](repeating: 0xFF204080, count: rows*cols) //DarkBlue
rgbArray[0] = 0xFFFF0000 // Red
rgbArray[1] = 0xFF00FF00 // Green
rgbArray[2] = 0xFF000001 // Black
let bytesPerRow = cols * 4

CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, cols, rows,
kCVPixelFormatType_BGRA32, &baseAddr, bytesPerRow, nil, nil, nil,
&pixelBuffer)

//...

print(pixelBuffer == nil) // false
print(CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer) == nil) // false, (CIImage is NOT nill) 
                                                  // but the result is not correct.
```

#### Expect

[image]

#### Result

[image]

Is there an alternative way that I can create `CVPixelBuffer`

- with final as YUV422 format
- Capable to set each component (Y,U,V) for all pixels